# Parse DateTime With Time (string)

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am receiving an "Incorrect Format" error when trying to Parse a Date (DateTime) and a Time (string) together from two parts of a QueryString.

Any help appreciated in resolving this.  Thanks!

```
var EventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["date"]);
string EventStartTime = Request.QueryString["time"];

DateTime newDateTime = 
  EventStartDate.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(EventStartTime, "H:mm:ss", null));
```

More detail below...

```
EventStartDate = 3/5/2016 12:00:00 AM

EventStartTime = 8:00:00 PM

Error:
Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 
Line 8:          string EventStartTime = Request.QueryString["time"];
Line 9:  
Line 10:         DateTime newDateTime = EventStartDate.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(EventStartTime, "hh:mm:ss", null));
```

Comment: What is the value of `Request.QueryString["date"]` and `Request.QueryString["time"]` _exactly_?

Comment: @SonerGönül  Thank you for the reply.  Added additional detail above, at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `HH`. Please use `HH` instead of `H`. Hope it will work.

```
DateTime newDateTime = 
  EventStartDate.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(EventStartTime, "HH:mm:ss", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming that your time is in the format **00:00:00**

```
DateTime newDateTime = EventStartDate.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(EventStartTime, "hh\\:mm\\:ss", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture` settings. Looks like `3/5/2016 12:00:00 AM` is not one of them. Also your `CurrentCulture` *may* have [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator) and [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator) properties as an empty strings.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) with a custom format and a specific culture setting like

```
var EventStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["date"], 
                                         "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You said your `EventStartTime` is `8:00:00 PM` and you try to parse it to `TimeSpan` but since a `TimeSpan` is a time interval, those designators have *no* meaning with them and they are not supported in as an input format as well.

If your string really have those designator, you need to remove them like;

```
string EventStartTime = Request.QueryString["time"].Replace("AM", "")
                                                   .Replace("PM", "").Trim();
```

then you can parse it to `TimeSpan` like;

```
var StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse(EventStartTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

as last, add it to your `EventStartDate` like;

```
var newDateTime = EventStartDate.Add(StartTime);
```